# Specification Pattern in a separate Project?

Tags: domain-driven-design, specification-pattern

I'm planning to use "Specification pattern" to validate my domain objects in my solution.

Where is the "correct" place to put the "specification" classes in my solution? Should I create a dedicated project that contains the "specification" classes, or should I chuck them into Domain or Business project layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you feel is the right place to achieve functional cohesiveness i.e. keep functionally related artifacts together so they change together, change is localized, easy to find stuff